# Don't get selected value which is retrieved from mysql database selected

Tags: php, mysqli

I was trying to get selected value selected from database, but it does not work for some reason.
I do not know what do I need to change, I am using function to store articles in database, and I am using the same function to get article that is selected in database. 
Function artikli:

```
function article() {
  $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
  $link->set_charset("utf8");
  $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `artikli` ORDER BY `Id` ASC ");
  echo '<option value="">Select article: </option>';
  while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  echo '<option value= "' .$record['Id']. '">' . $record['ArtCode'] ."-|-". $record['ArtName'] . ' </option>';
} 
}
```

In insert form this function works and insert an article. Now, in edit form, I want to get an article that is inserted. 
First I retrieve article from another table and I get value.

```
 $article = $r['ArtPalArticle'];
```

I get for ex. value 18. All values are integers.

```
$article = 18;

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label>Article</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="article" value = "<?php echo $article; selected?>">
    <option value=<?php echo $article?> selected></option>
    <?php article(); ?>
  </select>                                       
</div>
```

Could anyone give me hint, do I need to change function or I missed the code below function. It would be better for me to keep function same and change code below in select section

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket for the function `article`.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to write it. But it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the `id` with inserted `id` in the function. You can try this -

```
function article($articleId = null) {
  $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
  $link->set_charset("utf8");
  $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `artikli` ORDER BY `Id` ASC ");
  echo '<option value="">Select article: </option>';
  while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<option value= "' .$record['Id']. '" ' . ((!empty($articleId) && $articleId == $record['Id']) ? 'selected' : '' ) . '>' . $record['ArtCode'] ."-|-".     $record['ArtName'] . ' </option>';
  } 
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <label>Article</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="article">
    <?php 
    if(!empty($article)) { // at the time of edit
       article($article); 
    } else {
       article();
    }
    ?>
  </select>                                       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    function article( $article_id='' )
        {
            $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
            $link->set_charset("utf8");
            $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `artikli` ORDER BY `Id` ASC ");

            echo '<option value="">Select article: </option>';

            while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    if( !empty($article_id) )
                        {
                            if( $record['Id'] == $article_id )
                                echo '<option value= "' .$record['Id']. '" selected>' . $record['ArtCode'] ."-|-". $record['ArtName'] . ' </option>';
                            else
                                echo '<option value= "' .$record['Id']. '">' . $record['ArtCode'] ."-|-". $record['ArtName'] . ' </option>';
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            echo '<option value= "' .$record['Id']. '">' . $record['ArtCode'] ."-|-". $record['ArtName'] . ' </option>';
                        }
                }
        }

    ?>



    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <label>Article</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="article" id="article">
        <?php article( $article ); ?>
      </select>                                       
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you describe your solution and why it solves the problem? This just looks just like copy/pasted code right now.